# Get specific model in H2O stacked model

Tags: python, h2o

So I have trained several GBM models using GridSearch in H2O.

I then trained an ensemble model like so:

```
from h2o.estimators.stackedensemble import H2OStackedEnsembleEstimator

#List of all models in the GridSearch
all_model_ids=grid_search_gbm.model_ids


ensemble = H2OStackedEnsembleEstimator(
    model_id = 'ensemble_gbm' ,
    base_models = all_model_ids
)

ensemble.train(
    x=training_columns, 
    y=response_column,
    training_frame=train,
)
```

I can't how ever extract only specific models from "grid_search_gbm" and feed it into "H2OStackedEnsembleEstimator()". Is there a method for extracting this? For example the 3 best models in 'grid_search_gbm'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
grid_search_gbm.model_ids[:3]
```

it should give you the same model ids as

```
grid_search_gbm.sorted_metric_table()['model_ids'][:3]
```

Comment: But don't I just get a string with the ID's then? What I want is the model it self. Example: 
grid_search_rf.model_ids[:3] 

[u'Grid_DRF_py_53_sid_a1ca_model_python_1513162115962_79468_model_11',
 u'Grid_DRF_py_53_sid_a1ca_model_python_1513162115962_79468_model_4',
 u'Grid_DRF_py_53_sid_a1ca_model_python_1513162115962_79468_model_7']

I want to predict using the first model, like so somehow, but below is just the string and not the model itself 

Grid_DRF_py_53_sid_a1ca_model_python_1513162115962_79468_model_11.predict(test_frame)

Comment: I thought you wanted to replace your variable `all_model_ids` with a subset of ids. You can use `h2o.get_model('a_model_id')` to get the model from the id. But since you used model ids here: `base_models = all_model_ids` I assumed you just want to extract specific model ids to pass to the stack?